# Calculate $P'(x)$ for $x \in (-1,1)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

> $P$ is a power series with
>   $P(x)=x-\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5-\frac{1}{7}x^7+\cdots$
>
> Calculate $P'(x)$ for $x \in (-1,1)$

When I read this task (not homework), I got some questions:

1) Can I just derivate $P(x)$ now and write "$+\cdots$" as above?

2) What am I supposed to do with the given interval $(-1, 1)$? I really got no idea what to do with that. Only thing that comes to my mind is, insert $-1$ and $1$ into the derivated $P'(x)$ but what's the point of doing that anyway...?

$$P'(x) = 1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots$$

Very confusing task for me..

Edit: Instead of inserting $-1$ and $1$ into the $P'(x)$ maybe it would make more sense checking what value you get for $x$ for $P'(x) = 0$?
And after that, check if the value lies in the interval.

Comment: "Count"? What does that mean in this context?

Comment: Charge / estimate / calculate sorry my English isn't that good.

Comment: No worries! The word you want to use is 'calculate' perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P'(x)=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\ldots$ is a geometric series, and converges to $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: How do you know it converges to this?
I have converted $P'(x)$ to $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k}\cdot(-1)^{k}$.
Did you do that as well for your result? 
Now I'm trying to find out where this converges to, will post soon.

Edit: It will converge to $|-x^{2}|$

What do you think about that?

Comment: @cnmesr The geometric series is the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ar^k$ and you should just memorize that this sum converges to $\frac{a}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$.  Now take $a=1$ and $r=-x^2$.

Comment: Oh now I understand everything, thank you again! :)
Also thank to everyone else who posted and editted my topic!

Answer (score 1):

The reason they mention that $x\in(-1,1)$, which is I think the main source of your confusion, is so that you can perform things like integration and differentiation as you would a polynomial, termwise.

As long as $x$ is inside the radius of convergence, 
$$P'(x)=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots$$
Which as others have mentioned converges to $$\frac{1}{1-(-x^2))}=\frac{1}{1
+x^2}$$
by noticing that this series has a similar form to the geometric series with substitution $y=-x^2$